# Group date field by day for chart

Tags: views, charts

I have a custom database table with a datetime column that I have made accessible to Views. I want to create a line charts of number of rows per day but I can't get the View right.

With aggregation on I have a COUNT on my ID field and I'm trying to group on my date field by day (it currently has year -month - day - hour - minute - second). I have set the date format to d/m/Y and aggregation to group results together but they are still separate.

[image]

Obviously this makes for a pretty bad line chart

[image]

What I really want is

```
18/01/2017    23
19/01/2017    25
20/01/2017    19
```

I tried the Views Date Format SQL Field module (dev version too) but it doesn't seem to work as I don't get an option to format my date as SQL.

Is this possible in Views?

Comment: About the "Views Date Format SQL Field"-module you mentioned, do you mean https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql ? I.e. without the "field"-part of it? Also, are you using any (contributed) charting module for such charts? If so which one? FYI: tagging a question with "charts" doesn't automatically mean "I'm using the ***Charts*** module", which is why I wonder ... 1 more question: how about an alternative to using the Views module to create such a similar chart (which uses a free of charge, and open source, charting engine ...)?

Comment: Yes, that's the module I meant. I've tried both the Charts module and the Visualization module, same problem for both. I've not tried it without Views yet, I though this kind of grouping would be something Views could do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way to do this by rewriting the field described in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/charts/issues/2915097. There is also grouping enabled now if you want to stack your charts. Please download the latest -dev version.